# Unable to import cartopy

Tags: python, installation, import, google-colaboratory, cartopy

After Installing cartopy on google-colab, I was not able to import it:

```
!pip install cartopy
import cartopy

ImportError: cannot import name lgeos
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to install Cartopy in a Colab is by using the Conda environment. So we need to install the following:

```
#1|Install Conda environment on Colab
!pip install -q condacolab
import condacolab
condacolab.install()
```

Then,

```
#2|Install cartopy 
!mamba install -q -c conda-forge cartopy
```

After that,

```
#3|imoprt cartopy 
import cartopy
```

Answer (score 7):

Yes, by downgrading shapely:

```
pip install shapely==1.8.5
```

worked for me. (in google colab)

Answer (score 5):

I experienced the same issue (*not* using `google-colab`), which appears to stem from this Cartopy/Shapely `v2.0` compatibility issue: https://github.com/SciTools/cartopy/issues/2076.

More trace:

```py
import cartopy.trace
  File "lib/cartopy/trace.pyx", line 77, in init cartopy.trace
ImportError: cannot import name lgeos
```

I use pip, and **explicitly downgrading Shapely to version `1.8.5` worked for me.**